# paging without postback using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, aspxgridview

I am using Gridview. There are several pages. I want to go to the next page without post-back.
I have already tried by setting `EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks = "true"` but then i found i will not work if there is any TemplateColumn. So how could i have a solution? Here are my sample code...can anyone help?

```
<AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="GridAlternateRowStyle"></AlternatingItemStyle>
              <ItemStyle CssClass="GridRowStyle"></ItemStyle>
              <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" CssClass="GridColumnHeaderStyle"></HeaderStyle>
              <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle"></FooterStyle>
              <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateColumn>
                  <HeaderStyle Width="25px"></HeaderStyle>
                  <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckAll" language="javascript" onclick="return CheckAll_onclick(this.checked)"
                      Runat="server" />
                  </HeaderTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="DeleteThis" language="javascript" onclick="return DeleteThis_onclick(this.checked)"
                      runat="server" />
                  </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn>
                  <HeaderStyle Width="100px"></HeaderStyle>
                  <HeaderTemplate>
                    Code
                  </HeaderTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton id=Code onclick=EditItem runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "EmployeeCode") %>'>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="EmployeeName" HeaderText="Name"></asp:BoundColumn>
              </Columns>
              <PagerStyle NextPageText="" PrevPageText="" Mode="NumericPages" CssClass="ControlLinkButtonStyle" Position="TopAndBottom"></PagerStyle>
            </asp:datagrid>
```

Comment: Did you add `UpdatePanel` and try what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use [client side GridView funcitionality](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1738)? Look at the code below

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="_gridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" KeyFieldName="id" DataSourceID="ProjectsCenterDataSource" ClientInstanceName="_gridView">
....
</dx:ASPxGridView>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#button").click(function(){
          _gridView.NextPage(); // or _gridView.GotoPage(10)
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But there occur an error when i write the tag in the HTML page then the design view shows like " Error Creating Control - _gridViewThis control cannot be displayed because its TagPrefix is not registered in this Web Form".

Comment: Could you provide a code that you have and specify DevExpress version?